# Stale exception web scraping selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to grab information from tripadvisor.  I sometimes get

Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.73)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.4 x86_64)

and then the element is just whatever I assign it to.  How can I fix my code to handle the issue and then figure out a solution to it instead of re running the code?

```
  def getElements(driver):
        elements = []
        for dd in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'ui_button original')]"):
            try:
                if dd.text == "Book Now":
                    elements.append(dd)
            except Exception as ee:
                print ee
        return elements 

def getBookingPartner(driver, ibInfo):
    data = []
    i = 0 
    elements = []
    time.sleep(2)
    elements = getElements(driver)
    elementCounter = 0
    while(elements == [] or elementCounter >5):
        elements = getElements(driver)
        elementCounter+=1

    print "Length of elements should be > 0 : " + str(len(elements))
    for ii in ibInfo:
        if ii[0] == "Yes":
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            bookingPartner = "Error"    
            print ii    
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            try:
                elements[i].click()
                driver.implicitly_wait(3)
                driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
            except Exception as ee:
                try:
                    driver.refresh()
                    getElements(driver)[i].click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
                except Exception as ee:
                    print "Stale Exception...."
                    print ee    
            try:
                driver.implicitly_wait(3)
                driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'book_now')]")[1].click()
                driver.implicitly_wait(1)
                page = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)
                bookingPartner = page.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'custServiceMsg')]//text()")[0].split("will")[0].strip()                    
            except:
                try:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'book_now')]")[1].click()
                    time.sleep(2)
                    page = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)
                    bookingPartner = page.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'custServiceMsg')]//text()")[0].split("will")[0].strip()                    
                except:
                    try:
                        bookingPartner = page.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'custServiceMsg')]//text()")[1].split("will")[0].strip()
                    except Exception as ee:
                        bookingPartner = "Error"
                        print "error"
            i+=1

            if bookingPartner == "The remainder":
                bookingPartner = page.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'custServiceMsg')]//text()")[1].split("will")[0].strip()

            if len(driver.window_handles) > 1:
                driver.close()
                driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])

            print bookingPartner

            data.append([ii[0], ii[1], bookingPartner])
        else:
            data.append([ii[0], ii[1], "N/A"])
            ii.extend(["N/A"])

        print data
    return data
```

Answer (score 2):

A [Stale Element Reference Exception](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) occurs when an element:

1. Has been deleted
2. Is no longer attached to the DOM (as in your case)
3. Has changed

From the docs:

> You should discard the current reference you hold and replace it, possibly by locating the element again once it is attached to the DOM.

i.e.: "Find" the element again.

You'll need to modify the code to catch this error for the appropriate step.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('something leaves dom')
# ... do other actions which change the page and then later...
try:
    elem.click()
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('something leaves dom')
    elem.click()
```

Make a re-usable a version if you need it extensively for several elements.

Btw, you **should not be catching `Exception`** in your code. Be specific about which ones you want to handle.