# Why do I get StaleElementReferenceException when I "read" the text contents of a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

The issue occurs only when I try to collect ("crawl") the contents of a table twice. The first time that I read the table's contents is successful but the second time always fails.

This happens only with the Chrome browser (Version 74 with a corresponding chromedriver) . I tried the same with FireFox and it never occurs. I found a certain workaround in Chrome, which doesn't make any sense but it does the job.

When I "go" to other screen than the one that includes the table and then return back then the table crawling succeeds.

The following is the function that I use in order to collect the table:

```
def Get_Faults_List(Port_Number=None, PSU=None, Retries=5):
    for attempt in range(Retries):
        try:
            if Port_Number:
                # Show the Faults view in the context of "Port_Number"
                Device_Panel_Frame.Click_Port(self, Port_Number)
            elif PSU:
                if not Device_Panel_Frame.Click_PSU(self, PSU):
                    return None
            Left_Panel_Frame.Click_Fault(self)

            self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
            Main_Body = self.driver.find_element_by_name('main_page')
            self.driver.switch_to.frame(Main_Body)
            alarms_tab = self.driver.find_element_by_id('tab_alarms')
            alarms_tab.click()
            Fault_Screen = self.driver.find_element_by_name('faults')
            self.driver.switch_to.frame(Fault_Screen)
            # the rows that the following variable collect are automatically
            # the relevant fault lines. The XPATH that was used omits the two
            # irrelevant lines
            faultTable_rows = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=3, poll_frequency=0.5).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='faultTab']//tr[not(@id or @style)]")))

            current_faults = []
            row_index = 0
            for row in faultTable_rows:  # Go through each of the rows
                current_faults.append([])
                # Collect all the column elements of a certain row into a list
                faultTable_row_cols = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
                for col in faultTable_row_cols:
                    # Each row of the Faults table is separated into 5 columns each column holds a string
                    current_faults[row_index].append(col.text)
                row_index += 1

            break
        except:
            print(attempt + 1, 'attempt failed', Retries - (attempt + 1), 'to go')
            self.Refresh_Screen()
            sleep(5)
            continue
```

I will succeed to collect the table's contents also if I will open a new browser. By the way, the failure always occurs at the first line (after the header) of the following table. The line is `current_faults[row_index].append(col.text)` and I don't see why. The exception doesn't make any sense.

Is there another way to efficiently crawl the table's contents ?

The table:
[image]

Comment: I am still looking for an algorithm that will manage to crawl those kind of tables with success, By the way, I found out that the following line code ' current_faults[row_index].append(col.text) ' is the one that sometimes gets the StaleElementReferenceException. It seems like collecting the "cell" text sometimes fails. But, when it fails it won't help even if I refresh the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34148064/8179099) for the reason you get the `Stale Element Reference Exception`.

> A [Stale Element Reference Exception](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) occurs when an element:
>
> 1. Has been deleted
> 2. Is no longer attached to the DOM (as in your case)
> 3. Has changed
>
> From the docs:
>
> > You should discard the current reference you hold and replace it, possibly by locating the element again once it is attached to the DOM.
>
> i.e.: "Find" the element again.

## My suggestion is to capture the HTML and loop over it:

You can use `driver.page_source` then [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as such:

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

This should be implemented after you switch frames.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Every time that I call the function 'Get_Faults _List()' I am discarding the reference that I had to the table, when I last called this function. If I understand it right, finding the table in the hierarchy is involved with a new reference, and this is done every time that I call the function.

Comment: By the way, regarding your suggestion. By doing so, I will actually read the whole page, from the device, only once. Than, all the parsing can be done "offline"

Comment: regarding my suggestion... you can do it "off-line" yet if it's dynamic things might change... take that into consideration...

Comment: And regarding your explanation for the reason that I get the ' Stale Element Reference Exception ' could it be that I get a new reference for the table, or its cells, during the parsing process ? If so, I can't understand it, because I always get this issue (only with Chrome) when I am staying in the same view.

Comment: Check this out... https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp you might be getting the edge case!

Comment: I am trying to scrape the specific iframe that holds the relevant table. I am able to find the iframe and isolate it but I can't grab its contents. Is there a method to do that ? Now I am trying another way to do that by switching to the I frame and then grab the source. I can't locate the relevant table from this source. But at least I know that this is a different source than the one that i take without switching frames. How should I continue from here ?

Comment: I located the relevant table from the source that I took after switching to the relevant frame. But I don't see its actual contents. How should I continue from here ? Is there a way to see the actual contents that is seen in the DOM ?

Comment: I am at work so I can't help much... but try printing the DOM after switching the driver to the iframe see if it's there. you might want to use `get_text()` on the table you are scraping see: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Comment: Thanks a lot. By taking the ' page_source ' of the certain iframe (after switching frames) I managed to parse the contents of the table that I was interested in

Comment: @MosheS. glad to help!